# How do I create a pandas dataframe to export this dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a function such that, I get an output as a dictionary:

```
def is_clocked(business_id):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        clocked_ind = get_business(API_KEY, business_id)
        clocked_ind1 = clocked_ind['hours']
    except:
        clocked_ind1 = 'None'
    return clocked_ind1
clocked_ind = is_clocked(b_id)
print(clocked_ind)
```

Output:

```
[{'open':  [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0},     
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, 
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, 
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, 
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, 
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, 
            {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}],
  'hours_type': 'REGULAR',
  'is_open_now': True}]
```

However, I want to export this output into excel such that I can separate each vertical into start 0 start 1 end 0 end 1 and so on. I used the below code but it is not exporting and not giving me any output. Please help on how to solve this issue and how I can create a loop for the same

```
merge_HOO = clocked_ind  
pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO) 
print(merge_HOO)
merge_HOO.to_csv('merge_HOO_test1.csv')
```

I am getting 
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_csv' error

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: I want the output in excel to be like this start 0 start 1 end 0 end 1 and so on.

Comment: That's still not clear. Can you edit your question with an example of your desired output written out in a table form?

Comment: I edited. but more than anything I just want to see an output. Currently not getting the output to export in csv

Comment: what is this output? `start 0 start 1 start 2 .... `

Comment: I am not getting any output or csv file. please see i have re edited

Comment: change `pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO)` to `merge_HOO=pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO) `

Comment: its still giving AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: impossible. the error should have changed.

Comment: merge_HOO = my_list  
merge_HOO=pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO) 
print(merge_HOO)
pd.to_csv('merge_HOO_test1.csv')
  ...
0 ...

[1 rows x 3 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-5d313411147b>", line 4, in <module>
    pd.to_csv('merge_HOO_test1.csv')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: `pd.to_csv('merge_HOO_test1.csv')` you never posted that code and yeah. module pandas has no attribute `to_csv`. it's merge_HOO that has this function

Comment: hours_type is_open_now open
0 REGULAR FALSE [{'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}]
My output in csv is like this. but I want it to be in a format where start is header on one column and under that 1100, end is the header on the next column and 2200 under that and the days are in one columns,etc